# Angularjs: Does manual bootstrapping has bad performance issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll explain it shortly hope you could provide your explanation in regards to this question.

What i currently have is a traditional AngularJS app while a certain div in my body includes the **ng-app** attribute and all scripts are located at the **end** of the body.

solution 1:

```
 <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
       <!--rest of the app's markup is here-->
    </div>

    <!--scripts at the end of the body-->
    <script ...></script> <!--app.js/entrypoint--> 
    <script ...></script> <!--configs--> 
    <script ...></script> <!--services-->
    <script ...></script> <!--controllers-->
</body>
```

Note that since the order of the scripts does matter, **i manually set it's order**.

Now my question is regarding how angular behaves when loading the page.
I wonder if the next way of writing the markup file has bad performance issue, while i made two changes:

1. I **removed the ng-app** attribute
2. I shuffled the scripts in such way it has **no ordering** now.

solution 2:

```
 <body>
        <div> <!--No ng-app attribute!!-->
           <!--rest of the app's markup is here-->
        </div>

        <!--manual bootstrapping-->
    <script>
     angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
    </script>

        <!--scripts at the end of the body without ordering-->
        <script ...></script> 
        <script ...></script> 
        <script ...></script>
        <script ...></script>
</body>
```

Here, the main idea was to remove the need of ordering the files manually, and to bootstrap angular app later (by adding the ng-app manually on document load).

Now please consider two facts:

1. There could be a lot of scripts files.
2. All these scripts could also be bundled into one file.

What im trying to understand is, is there any performance problem in any of the solutions? is any of it more ideal ?

Comment: As long as all the dependencies are available when it bootstraps can't see why any of this would be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that has no impact in performance (not one that angular has documented at least). The second solution is just an alternative way to bootstrap an angular application (better imo).

---

#### Why would you want to do this?

Sometimes you need to do some work before bootstrapping the application so synchronous scripts won't work. This is what you would do if, for example, you were using requireJS, webpack, etc. It also gives you more control over when your app actually start.

I would recommend though to move the bootstrapping to the end of the file so you are not relying on the fact that the `ready` function is async which makes it magically work even though you are calling it before all the scripts